# reinstalling development application on iphone

Tags: iphone, installation

I was able to build and install my app on my iphone. If I want to fix some issues and reinstall it, is there anything I should do before reinstalling? I do see the latest changes but some things are messed up.

Answer (score 0):

delete old application before installing new.... it will make sure that no data related to older application remains on iphone...

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing things from the older build then first of all delete the build from iPhone/iPod and then go to the folder where you have your xcode project now in that folder you should delete the folder "build". You can also do a "clean" after this, but that may not be necessary.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

madhup

Comment: I deleted the app from iphone. Then deleted the build folder and started again. The app runs fine on the simulator. It just stuck in one place on the device. How do I go about debugging the issue?